# Cloud Run with Fastly or Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, google-cloud-run, fastly

When I want to map a custom domain to my cloud run services. Is this a one time only thing I need to do via CNAME record? Or is this validated on a continuous basis?

I would like to have a CNAME record from Fastly which shield my Cloud Run service.
The same functionality applies on Cloudflare with a DNS record (without proxy) pointing to Cloud Run service and then enabling the proxy functionality. Everything seems to work fine (with Cloudflare) but I don't know if this will break in the future? I would also like to able to do the same for Fastly

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your DNS record for 2 things when doing a domain mapping of your Cloud Run service: domain ownership verification and domain mapping creation.

- The domain verification is a one time operation, once verified, you can clean up your DNS records.
- The actual mapping of the verified domain to the Cloud Run service requires to set either `CNAME` or `A` records, and these must stay in your DNS records in order for the mapping to keep working.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Wasn't sure that the domain verification was a one time operation.